# O brother where art thou tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I noticed that the tag description for [o-brother-where-art-thou](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/o-brother-where-art-thou) includes the line

"An optimistic young Hollywood actress gets caught up with a woman with amnesia in a dark adventure."

This has nothing to do with the movie. It seems to be part of the [mulholland-drive](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mulholland-drive) tag description.

(I'm asking this before editing because I know nothing about this community, and for all I know it could be an inside joke or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, we don't have inside jokes, as far as I'm aware...

Edit away.